# What does it mean that this patent is dead?

Tags: patent-applications, abandoned-patent

In reference to the patent: [US20080178629](https://www.google.com/patents/US20080178629)

The most recent legal event listed on this patent is "dead", what does that mean? Was it abandoned or does it mean that the application was denied for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

You can check [USPTO PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) to see a history of the patent prosecution. I glanced at the document. The examiner objected the application because its claims encompass dissimilar species and requested that the applicant elect the restriction. The applicant never responded and the application was deemed abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

The application has been abandoned.  This means that the applicant opted not to respond to an office action within the time allotted by the examiner (including all extensions) and the application went abandoned.  It never materialized into a patent.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents -answering old questions is encouraged but not when the answer adds nothing to existing answers.